# Transformed Primitives - Compute the inverse of a matrix without using any function

Tags: matrix, transform, transformation, raytracing

Let's say if I need to transform a cylinder, first I need to use a scaling matrix (sx, sy, sz) and multiply it with a translation matrix (tx, ty, tz) to form a new matrix that combined by these two matrix. => M = T*S.

Then I want to compute the inverse of a matrix M^-1 without using any function, I know that the inverse of a scaling matrix has a scale factors (1/sx, 1/sy, 1/sz) and a inverse of a translation matrix has (-tx, -ty, -tz), but how can I get M^-1 without any function in C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to scale a vector by some factors Sx, Sy, and Sz. The transformation matrix for this looks like:

```
Sx 0  0  0
0  Sy 0  0
0  0  Sz 0
0  0  0  1
```

Then, you want to translate the vector by some factors Tx, Ty, and Tz. The transformation matrix for this now looks like:

```
Sx 0  0  Tx
0  Sy 0  Ty
0  0  Sz Tz
0  0  0  1
```

The inverse of this matrix specifically is

```
1/Sx 0    0    -Tx/Sx
0    1/Sy 0    -Ty/Sy
0    0    1/Sz -Tz/Sz
0    0    0     1
```

.. as long as `Sx`, `Sy`, and `Sz` are all `!= 0`.

Depending on your application, you may be better off writing a general purpose matrix inversion method. Note that there are cases in which a transformation (or any) matrix is not invertible... like if your scaling factor in one or more of the dimensions is 0. More generally, a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero.